# Не дается сделать нормальный таймлайн ткинтер питон

Tags: python, tkinter

я 2 недели пытаюсь сделать плеер в ткинтере(python) но у меня 1)таймлайн не двигаеться 2)после завершение песни не включается следующая

````
import os
import pygame
import pickle
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Scale, filedialog, HORIZONTAL, Label, PhotoImage, Listbox
from time import gmtime, strftime
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3

pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 2, 2048)
pygame.mixer.init()

class Player(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title('Python Music Player')
        self.geometry("500x400")
        self.resizable(0, 0)
        # self.image = PhotoImage(file='bg.png')
        # self.label = Label(self, image=self.image)
        # self.label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        self.button1 = Button(self, text="Выберите песню", command=self.load_song)
        self.button1.pack()
        self.button2 = Button(self, text="Воспроизвести/Продолжить", command=self.play_song)
        self.button2.pack()
        self.button3 = Button(self, text="Пауза", command=self.pause_song)
        self.button3.pack()
        self.button4 = Button(self, text="Воспроизвести случайную песню", command=self.play_random_song)
        self.button4.pack()
        self.button5 = Button(self, text="Удалить песню", command=self.delete_song)
        self.button5.pack()
        self.song_label = Label(self, text="")
        self.song_label.pack()
        self.time_label = Label(self, text="Время: 00:00 | 00:00")
        self.time_label.pack()
        self.volume = Scale(self, from_=0, to_=100, resolution=1, orient=HORIZONTAL,
                            length=300, sliderlength=10, command=self.set_volume)
        self.volume.pack()
        self.volume.set(50)
        self.timeline = Scale(self, from_=0, to_=1000, resolution=1, orient=HORIZONTAL,
                              length=300, sliderlength=10, command=self.update_song_position, showvalue=0)
        self.timeline.pack()
        self.song_listbox = Listbox(self)
        self.song_listbox.pack()
        self.song_listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.select_song_from_list)
        self.song_loaded = False
        self.is_paused = False
        self.song_length_ms = 0
        self.song_start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        self.is_user_scrubbing = False
        self.timeline.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.start_scrub)
        self.timeline.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.end_scrub)
        self.update_timeline_music()
        self.song_history_file = "song_history.pkl"
        if os.path.isfile(self.song_history_file):
            with open(self.song_history_file, 'rb') as file:
                self.song_history = pickle.load(file)
                for song in self.song_history.values():
                    self.song_listbox.insert("end", song)
        else:
            self.song_history = {}
        self.bind(pygame.USEREVENT, self.handle_song_end)
    
    def select_song_from_list(self, event):
        selection = event.widget.curselection()
        if selection:
            index = selection[0]
            song_name = event.widget.get(index)
            for filename, name in self.song_history.items():
                if name == song_name:
                    self.song_file = filename
                    pygame.mixer.music.load(self.song_file)
                    audio = MP3(self.song_file)
                    self.song_length_ms = audio.info.length * 1000
                    self.timeline.config(to_=int(self.song_length_ms / 1000))
                    self.song_label.config(text=name)
                    self.play_song()
    
    def update_timeline_music(self):
        if not self.is_user_scrubbing:
            if pygame.mixer.music.get_busy() or self.is_paused:
                current_pos = pygame.time.get_ticks() - self.song_start_time
                pos_str = strftime("%M:%S", gmtime(int(current_pos / 1000)))
                length_str = strftime("%M:%S", gmtime(int(self.song_length_ms / 1000)))
                self.time_label.config(text="Время: {} | {}".format(pos_str, length_str))
                self.timeline.set(int(current_pos / 1000))
                self.timeline.update()
        self.after(1000, self.update_timeline_music)
    
    def update_song_position(self, _=None):
        if 'song_file' in dir(self) and pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
            pygame.mixer.music.play(0, self.timeline.get())
    
    def set_volume(self, volume):
        pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(int(volume) / 100)
    
    def load_song(self):
        self.song_file = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=os.getcwd(),
                                                    title="Выберите музыкальный файл",
                                                    filetypes=[("Audio files", "*.mp3 *.midi")])
        if self.song_file:
            pygame.mixer.music.load(self.song_file)
            self.song_loaded = True
            if self.song_file.endswith('.mp3'):
                audio = MP3(self.song_file)
                self.song_length_ms = audio.info.length * 1000
                self.timeline.config(to_=int(self.song_length_ms / 1000))
            song_file_name = os.path.basename(self.song_file)
            self.song_label.config(text=song_file_name)
            self.song_history[self.song_file] = song_file_name
            self.song_listbox.insert("end", song_file_name)
            with open(self.song_history_file, 'wb') as file:
                pickle.dump(self.song_history, file)
            self.play_song()
    
    def handle_song_end(self, event):
        if event.type == pygame.USEREVENT:
            self.play_next_song()
    
    def play_next_song(self):
        if len(self.song_listbox.curselection()) == 0:
            return
        current_song_index = self.song_listbox.curselection()[0]
        next_song_index = (current_song_index + 1) % self.song_listbox.size()
        self.song_listbox.selection_clear(0, self.song_listbox.size() - 1)
        self.song_listbox.selection_set(next_song_index)
        self.song_listbox.activate(next_song_index)
        self.select_song_from_list(None)
        
    def pause_song(self):
        if pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
            if self.is_paused:
                pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
                self.is_paused = False
            else:
                pygame.mixer.music.pause()
                self.is_paused = True
    
    def play_random_song(self):
        random_song = random.choice(list(self.song_history.keys()))
        pygame.mixer.music.load(random_song)
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
    
    def delete_song(self):
        if hasattr(self, 'song_file'):
            if self.song_file in self.song_history.keys():
                del self.song_history[self.song_file]
                self.song_listbox.delete(0, "end")
                for song in self.song_history.values():
                    self.song_listbox.insert("end", song)
                os.remove(self.song_file)
                self.song_file = None
                self.song_label.config(text="")
                self.timeline.config(to_=1000)
                self.time_label.config(text="Время: 00:00 | 00:00")
                pygame.mixer.music.stop()
    
    def start_scrub(self, event):
        self.is_user_scrubbing = True
    
    def end_scrub(self, event):
        self.is_user_scrubbing = False
        pygame.mixer.music.play(0, self.timeline.get())
    
    def record_music(self):
        with open("music_records.txt", "a") as file:
            record_str = "Название музыки: {}\\nВремя музыки: {}\\nКогда играла: {}\\n".format(
                self.song_label["text"], strftime("%M:%S", gmtime(int(self.song_length_ms / 1000))),
                strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            )
            file.write(record_str)
    
    def play_song(self):
        if self.song_loaded:
            pygame.mixer.music.play()
            self.song_start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
            self.record_music()
            self.update_timeline_music()

player = Player()
player.mainloop()```
````

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)